# How to find continuities with piecewise?

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x &\text{if}& x\le 0 \\ x^2 &\text{if}&  0\lt x\lt 1 \\ 2-x &\text{if}&x \ge 1\end{cases}$$

I don't understand how to begin solving this problem.Aren't continuities usually solved by looking at the denominator, setting it to zero and solving? There is no denominator in a piecewise function. Is this a trick question?

The Stackexchange site is glitching and it won't display the question properly. Here is the pastebin of the problem: http://pastebin.com/U4mAyvwn

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Since the function is continuous on open intervals, potential issues are at **endpoints**.
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x &\text{if}& x\le 0 \\ x^2 &\text{if}&  0\lt x\lt 1 \\ 2-x &\text{if}&x \ge 1.\end{cases}$$

Then here you just have to check if
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x)&=\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)\\
\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)&=\lim_{x \to 1^+}f(x).
\end{align}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand. How can I solve the problem if there are no denominators?

Comment: @user6050977 Continuity is about existence of limits. Of course if you are dealing with a function given in terms of a fraction, you will be careful with the denominator. But if there is no fraction, you just have to consider limit at potential points of the set that can bring issues.